# PMI-PMP relation

Tags: pmp, pmi-framework

I started a research about what is PMP.  For doing that I think a good idea is to become a member of a PMI Chapter.   I am mexican and there is a chapter here.

**Question**

**Can I enroll in other chapters as well?**

*I am interested in visiting Los Angeles, it is a good idea to pay L.A. Chapter fee now? Do I have better opportunities?*

**Can I expect to make some volunteering there if I am a PMI member?**

Comment: I don't believe there is any need to enroll in multiple chapters; depends on the length of your stay. I would advise you to contact the President of the chapter you intend to visit and ask them (http://pmi-la.org/) for rules about visiting members and about volunteer opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

PMI has some good information on their website around [volunteering opportunities](http://www.pmi.org/Get-Involved/Volunteer-Opportunities.aspx). Taking a quick look at their online system it looks like you aren't restricted geographically from searching for opportunities to volunteer. You may want to set up an account in their system and give it a try.